# jQuery — Variable not recognised but manual input of exact same value is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables

Best explained with code:

```
$(".myParent .myChild:nth-child(3n)").css('border-top-color','#ffffff');
```

> √ Works

```
myVar = "3n";
$(".myParent .myChild:nth-child(myVar)").css('border-top-color','#ffffff');
```

> X Doesn't work

This is obviously jQuery programming 101... but seriously, why on *earth* won't that work?!
I'm passing on the *same* thing!

I tried it as > myVar = 3n (no string), obviously that shouldn't work, and it didn't.

Comment: “jQuery Programming 101” — more like JavaScript 101.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you var has to be concatenated

```
 var myVar = "3n";

 $(".myParent .myChild:nth-child("+myVar+")").css('border-top-color','#ffffff');
```

Comment: Ah OK... so it's looking at the css as a string already so I have to go out the string to pick up the variable. Thanks a million.

Comment: @RGBK Yes but I wouldn't call it CSS to the right of the dot is CSS to the left is your jQuery selector 8 ^ )